# AWS CDK - Exclude stage name from logical ID of resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have a CDK project where initially it was deployed via CLI. I am now wrapping it in a pipelines construct.

Old:

```
Project  
|  
  Stacks  
  |
    Resources
```

New:

```
Project
|
  Pipeline  
  | 
    Stage
    |  
      Stacks  
      |
       Resources
```

The issue I'm running into is that there are resources I would rather not be deleted in the application, however adding the stage causes the logical ID's to change to `Stage-Stack-Resource` from `Stack-Resource`. I found [this article](https://aws-cdk.com/shorter-aws-cdk-logical-ids/) that claims you can provide an id of 'Default' to a resource, and cause it to go unused in the process of making the logical ID. however for some reason when I pass an Id of Default to the stage it simply uses that "Default" literal value instead of omitting it.

End goal is that I can keep my existing cloudformation resources, but have them deployed via this pipeline.

Comment: I have gone from the `aws cdk deploy` to building with `aws-cdk-lib/aws-codepipeline` and have not experienced this issue. It'd be great if you could include a little code and we can see the differences. I am following [this udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/create-continuous-delivery-pipelines-on-aws-using-cdk/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a full redeploy of the application. Luckily this was a development environment where trashing our data stores isn't a huge loss. But would be much more of a concern in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the logical id manually like this:

S3 example:

```
const cfnBucket = s3Bucket.node.defaultChild as aws_s3.CfnBucket;
cfnBucket.overrideLogicalId('CUSTOMLOGICALID');
```

However, if you did not specify a logical id initially and do it now, CloudFormation will delete the original resource and create a new one with the new custom logical id because CloudFormation identifies resources by their logical ID.

---

`Stage` is something you define and it is not related to CloudFormation. You are probably using it in your Stack name or in your Resource names and that's why it gets included in the logical id.

Based on your project description, the only option to not have any resources deleted is: make one of the pipeline stages use the exact same stack name and resource names (without `stage`) as the CLI deployed version.

Comment: I saw the override option, but considering I'm deploying something in the order of 100's of resources the solution doesn't scale well. To make that work I would have to add quite a bit of baggage to the codebase to do that for every resource in only one of two environments.